# How to Allow filtering of group rows in Ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

When I use the row grouping, the individual rows show up in the filter drop down and can be added/removed from filtering. The group itself though can not be selected. In order to filter out an entire group I have to figure out which items are in the group and de-select each one. Once they are all de-selected the group becomes hidden.

For example:

group1
row1
row2
group2
row3
row4

Filtering allows me to deselect row1, 2, 3, 4 but not group1, 2. If I deselect row3, 4 then group2 becomes hidden. I would like to see group1, 2 in the filter dropdown so I can filter at the group level and its corresponding rows are also hidden.

I have set filtermodal on page load to show few rows and when i deselect group from filter then its corresponding rows are not getting removed, i have to manually remove the rows and then the group gets removed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.